# Error al cargar imagenes en carousel booststrap

Tags: bootstrap, googlepagespeed

Tengo el siguiente código de `bootstrap` en el cual empleo el `carousel` pero de acuerdo a la verificación de `PageSpeed Insights` me sugiere lo siguiente

> Te recomendamos que uses la carga diferida con imágenes ocultas y que no aparecen en pantalla una vez que todos los recursos críticos hayan terminado de cargarse para reducir el tiempo que pasa hasta que la página es interactiva.

Con lo cual lo aplico y lo subo para verificar pero al momento de realizar la actualización de la pagina esas imágenes efectivamente no se cargar usando debido al uso de la etiqueta `amp-img` pero cuando ya el carousel continua para visualizarla tampoco se cargan, que esto realizando de manera errónea o por su defecto optar por otra opción.

```
 <div id="carouselMultiItemExample" class="carousel slide carousel-dark text-center" data-mdb-ride="carousel">
<!-- Controls -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">
  <button class="carousel-control-prev position-relative" type="button" data-mdb-target="#carouselMultiItemExample"
    data-mdb-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next position-relative" type="button" data-mdb-target="#carouselMultiItemExample"
    data-mdb-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
<!-- Inner -->
<div class="carousel-inner py-4">
  <!-- Single item -->
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../../assets/images/head/img-head-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="ENTERO (HOSO)" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">ENTERO (HOSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Es la forma mas natural del camarón, ya que es exportado de la misma forma que llega a nuestras
                instalaciones.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../../assets/images/head/img-head-002.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="ENTERO (HOSO)" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">ENTERO (HOSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                El camarón entero es manipulado y procesado de forma inmediata después de haber sido cosechado.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../../assets/images/head/img-head-003.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="ENTERO (HOSO)" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">ENTERO (HOSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Es un producto que tiene alta demanda mundial por su frescura, tamaño y sabor particular,
                esuno de los más solicitados en los mercados internacionales.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Single item -->
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/pyd/img-pyd-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="COLA (HLSO)" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">COLA (HLSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Es una de las maneras más tradicionales de exportación de camarón crudo.
                Para realizar este producto se le quita la cabeza al camarón.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/pyd/img-pyd-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="COLA (HLSO)" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">COLA (HLSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Es un producto que es solicitado constantemente por los distintos mercados del
                mundo, resalta por su frescura, textura firme y tamaño uniforme.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/pyd/img-pyd-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="COLA (HLSO)" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">COLA (HLSO)</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                La Cola de Camarón es un producto renombrado por los distintos mercados internacionales
                lo cual lo hace apetecible a los consumidores.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Single item -->
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/btf/img-btf-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="VALOR AGREGADO" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">VALOR AGREGADO</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Es estrictamente manipulado con todo el cuidado y procesado con la mejor calidad
                siguiendo todos estándares y protocolos de bioseguridad.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/btf/img-btf-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="VALOR AGREGADO" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">VALOR AGREGADO</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Se utiliza la más alta calidad de materia prima, nuestra gama de productos incluye
                las siguientes presentaciones P&D, PUD, PPV, entre otros.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="card">
            <amp-img src="../../assets/images/btf/img-btf-001.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="VALOR AGREGADO" ></amp-img>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">VALOR AGREGADO</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Nuestra principal fuente de pedidos de este producto es la Unión Europea y la república popular
                China.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Inner -->
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: Estás usando atributos data que no son propios de Boostrap, estás utilizando un framework adicional?

Comment: Cuando indicas sobre los atributos te refieres a <amp-img>?

Comment: `data-mdb-*` Eso es material design? Que versión estás usando exactamente? También puedes revisar sobre la etiqueta loading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#images_and_iframes

Comment: Si efectivamente uso Material Design for Bootstrap en ese parte para el carousel, esto afectaria directamente en que no se pueda realizar lo de las cargas diferidas